# integrationDriver in integration_test_driver.dart has documentation for a parameter named onScreenshot but does not have the actual implementation

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, integration-testing, flutter-web

**flutter/packages/integration_test/lib/integration_test_driver.dart**

`/// onScreenshotcan be used to process the screenshots taken during the test. /// An example could be that this callback compares the byte array against a baseline image, /// and it returnstrueif both images are equal. /// /// As a result, returningfalsefromonScreenshot will make the test fail.`

But in **flutter/packages/integration_test/lib/integration_test_driver_extended.dart** have **onScreenshot()** callback but does not have **responseDataCallback()** parameter: though in both cases it return null after all test case execution.
**How to capture screenshot using **flutter/packages/integration_test/lib/integration_test_driver.dart** package if it doesn't not contain onScreenshot() callback?**

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94881

Flutter doctor:

```
`C:\Users\Ext07696\FlutterProjects\signify-bics-frontend>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.62.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!``
```

Answer (score 2):

It does have.
You can use like this:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver_extended.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final FlutterDriver driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  await integrationDriver(
    driver: driver,
    onScreenshot: (String screenshotName, List<int> screenshotBytes) async {
      final File image = File('screenshots/$screenshotName.png');
      image.writeAsBytesSync(screenshotBytes);
      // Return false if the screenshot is invalid.
      return true;
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 'import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver_extended.dart' import.

Comment: is there any way to implement both packaged of test_driver and test_driver_extended if I want to do integration and performance tests in the same file?

Comment: Use a prefix: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#specifying-a-library-prefix